# Getting the sql server default backup folder on Linux with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linux, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

For SQL Server on Windows for getting default backup folder we can use `master.dbo.xp_instance_regread`:

```sql
    DECLARE @HkeyLocal nvarchar(18) = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE';
    DECLARE @MSSqlServerRegPath nvarchar(31) = N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer';
    DECLARE @InstanceRegPath sysname = @MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\MSSQLServer';

    DECLARE @BackupDirectory nvarchar(512)
    if 1=isnull(cast(SERVERPROPERTY('IsLocalDB') as bit), 0)
    SET @BackupDirectory=cast(SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultdatapath') as nvarchar(512))
    else
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'BackupDirectory', @BackupDirectory OUTPUT;

    SELECT @BackupDirectory AS SQLServerBackupDirectory;
```

But for Linux it does not work. Can anyone help with T-SQL approach (I only find SSMS solution [here](https://www.mssqlonlinux.com/blog/change-default-backup-directory-in-sql-server-on-linux))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never found a non-registry way to get the backup directory reliably in t-sql. I usually just do a replace of /data/ to /backup/ since at default install it's relation to the data directory is clear. This does not directly answer your question but it's a working way provided you have not done individual directory customization during install.

```
-- for one of my databases, [dharma] in my linux test-bed.
declare @bkup nvarchar(1024)
set @bkup = replace(cast(SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultdatapath') as nvarchar(512)),'/data/','/backup/') + 'dharma.bak'
backup database dharma to disk = @bkup
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, waiting correct alternative (default backup folder can be changed in any time) for some days and if no luck I will approve your answer.

Comment: I changed the default backup directory on my RHEL clone, it stores the new value in /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf, not in master or msdb as I hoped. Hopefully at some point they update the registry stored procs to pull values from *nix config files. They currently wont even allow you to change it in SSMS. Only shell.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server v2019, Microsoft enhanced ServerProperty to expose InstanceDefaultBackupPath.  Spoke of same here ( https://learningintheopen.org/2020/06/08/sql-server-configuration-default-directories/ )